# How to use sugar orm to run migrations

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I have an existing Android application which pre packages a database called app.db . The app.db file resides in src/main/res/raw . On starting the application it gets copied over to data/data/app/databases.

The current version of db is 2, which was set using SQLiteOpenHelper. I don't want to bind this db to any model object but only add or delete rows from it by running some dmls.

The Manifest looks like this:

```
<application
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
   android:name="MyApplication">
   ...
 <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="app.db" />
 <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="3" />
 <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
</application>
```

MyAppplication class extends SugarApp.
 I created a folder called sugar_upgrades in assets and created a file in it called 3.sql. This file contains a script like:

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE id = 53;
```

But after running the application this script never runs. I think the issue is Sugar is expecting the db to be present in /data folder. But in the start of the application it is present in res/raw and that is why it is not able to pick it up. Any way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write an answer rather than a comment because I needed some extra formatting help. I will update this post as needed.

First of all, you should look at the `SchemaGenerator` class [here](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/SchemaGenerator.java). You will notice that there are a couple of log statements that could help narrow down your issue. Here is one for example:

```
Log.i("Sugar", "not a sugar script. ignored." + file);
```

So I would suggest searching your logcat output for the "Sugar" tag and see if there is any useful information that is shown.

A second place that would be valuable to debug would be the  `SugarDb` class found [here](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/SugarDb.java). This class extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and implements the `onUpgrade` method:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    schemaGenerator.doUpgrade(sqLiteDatabase, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

It might be helpful to clone the Sugar source code and compile the project manually and add it as a dependency. Then you will be able testing your SQL query directly on the SQLite database like so:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    schemaGenerator.doUpgrade(sqLiteDatabase, oldVersion, newVersion);

    sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ?", new String[]{"53"});
}
```

Finally, if you discover the the data is not available like you suspect in the /data folder at startup you would have to modify the Sugar source code to alter the data once it has been loaded.